# Multithreading creates slow repository calls

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot

I am creating a report api endpoint for a dashboard. The report initially calls 24 threads (layer1), which then each call an additional 4 threads (layer2). Layer2Service then calls a repository to get data. What I am seeing from the results is that my Layer2Service begins to slow down during each thread. It seems like Spring might be pooling these repository calls. Why are my threads slowing down?

```
@Service
public class BaseService {

   @Autowired
   private Layer1Service layer1Service;

   public BaseLayer baseLayer() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

       Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
       List<CompletableFuture<Layer1Service.Layer1>> threadQueue = new ArrayList<>();

       int maxThreads = 24;
       int threadCount = 0;
       while(threadCount < maxThreads) {
           CompletableFuture<Layer1Service.Layer1> threadAsync = layer1Service.layer1();
           threadQueue.add(threadAsync);
           threadCount++;
       }

       CompletableFuture<Void> allDoneFutures =
            CompletableFuture.allOf(threadQueue.toArray(new CompletableFuture[threadQueue.size()]));
       CompletableFuture<List<Layer1Service.Layer1>> allCompletableFuture = allDoneFutures.thenApply(future -> {
           List<Layer1Service.Layer1> list = new ArrayList<>();
           for (CompletableFuture<Layer1Service.Layer1> completableFuture : threadQueue) {
               Layer1Service.Layer1 join = completableFuture.join();
               list.add(join);
           }
           return list;
       });


       List<Layer1Service.Layer1> results = allCompletableFuture.get();

       stopWatch.stop();

       BaseLayer baseLayer = new BaseLayer();
       baseLayer.setThreadResults(results);

       String result = "Base layer: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " Completion time: " + stopWatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
       baseLayer.setTimingResult(result);

       return baseLayer;
   }

   @Data
   public class BaseLayer {

       public String timingResult;
       public List<Layer1Service.Layer1> threadResults;
   }
}
```

Layer1Services creates 4 more threads from Layer2Service.

```
@Service
public class Layer1Service {

   @Autowired
   private Layer2Service layer2Service;

   @Async("dashboard")
   public CompletableFuture<Layer1> layer1() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

       Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
       List<CompletableFuture<String>> threadQueue = new ArrayList<>();

       int maxThreads = 4;
       int threadCount = 0;
       while(threadCount < maxThreads) {
           CompletableFuture<String> threadAsync = layer2Service.layer2(Thread.currentThread().getId());
           threadQueue.add(threadAsync);
           threadCount++;
       }

       CompletableFuture<Void> allDoneFutures =
            CompletableFuture.allOf(threadQueue.toArray(new CompletableFuture[threadQueue.size()]));
       CompletableFuture<List<String>> allCompletableFuture = allDoneFutures.thenApply(future -> {
           List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
           for (CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture : threadQueue) {
               String join = completableFuture.join();
               list.add(join);
           }
           return list;
       });

       List<String> results = allCompletableFuture.get();

       stopWatch.stop();

       Layer1 layer1 = new Layer1();
       layer1.setThreadResults(results);

       String result = "Layer 1: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " Completion time: " + stopWatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
       layer1.setTimingResult(result);

       return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(layer1);
   }

   @Data
   public class Layer1 {

       public String timingResult;
       public List<String> threadResults;
   }
}
```

Layer2 interacts with the repository, this is where the slowdown begins to happen. There are 24 * 4 = 96 threads or calls to the db that happen at close to the same time.

```
@Service
public class Layer2Service {

   @Autowired
   private LanguageRepository languageRepository;

   @Async("dashboard")
   public CompletableFuture<String> layer2(long threadId) {
       Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
       final Optional<Language> firstById = languageRepository.findById(Long.valueOf(1));
       stopWatch.stop();
       String result = "Layer1: " + threadId + " Layer2: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " Runtime: " + stopWatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
       return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result);
   }
```

To manage the pool size I have created a custom executor:

```
@Bean(name = "dashboard")
public Executor asyncDashboard() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(150);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(225);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(300);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Dashboard-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

results:

```
{
  "timingResult": "Base layer: 65 Completion time: 5295",
  "threadResults": [
    {
      "timingResult": "Layer 1: 93 Completion time: 2439",
      "threadResults": [
        "Layer1: 93 Layer2: 117 Runtime: 2346",
        "Layer1: 93 Layer2: 145 Runtime: 2346",
        "Layer1: 93 Layer2: 146 Runtime: 2347",
        "Layer1: 93 Layer2: 147 Runtime: 2416"
      ]
    },
    {
      "timingResult": "Layer 1: 94 Completion time: 2901",
      "threadResults": [
        "Layer1: 94 Layer2: 116 Runtime: 2417",
        "Layer1: 94 Layer2: 148 Runtime: 2416",
        "Layer1: 94 Layer2: 150 Runtime: 2803",
        "Layer1: 94 Layer2: 156 Runtime: 2876"
      ]
    },
    {
      "timingResult": "Layer 1: 95 Completion time: 3372",
      "threadResults": [
        "Layer1: 95 Layer2: 115 Runtime: 2419",
        "Layer1: 95 Layer2: 149 Runtime: 2796",
        "Layer1: 95 Layer2: 157 Runtime: 3343",
        "Layer1: 95 Layer2: 163 Runtime: 3342"
      ]
    },
    {
      "timingResult": "Layer 1: 96 Completion time: 2913",
      "threadResults": [
        "Layer1: 96 Layer2: 114 Runtime: 1463",
        "Layer1: 96 Layer2: 118 Runtime: 2346",
        "Layer1: 96 Layer2: 144 Runtime: 2416",
        "Layer1: 96 Layer2: 151 Runtime: 2887"
      ]
    },
    {
      "timingResult": "Layer 1: 97 Completion time: 1479",
      "threadResults": [
        "Layer1: 97 Layer2: 112 Runtime: 1474",
        "Layer1: 97 Layer2: 119 Runtime: 999",
        "Layer1: 97 Layer2: 121 Runtime: 1001",
        "Layer1: 97 Layer2: 122 Runtime: 1448"
      ]
    },
    {
      "timingResult": "Layer 1: 98 Completion time: 1480",
      "threadResults": [
        "Layer1: 98 Layer2: 113 Runtime: 1001",
        "Layer1: 98 Layer2: 123 Runtime: 999",
        "Layer1: 98 Layer2: 124 Runtime: 1475",
        "Layer1: 98 Layer2: 125 Runtime: 985"
      ]
    },
    {
      "timingResult": "Layer 1: 99 Completion time: 1950",
      "threadResults": [
        "Layer1: 99 Layer2: 111 Runtime: 1475",
        "Layer1: 99 Layer2: 126 Runtime: 1466",
        "Layer1: 99 Layer2: 139 Runtime: 1893",
        "Layer1: 99 Layer2: 140 Runtime: 1934"
      ]
    },
    {
      "timingResult": "Layer 1: 100 Completion time: 3243",
      "threadResults": [
        "Layer1: 100 Layer2: 110 Runtime: 1475",
        "Layer1: 100 Layer2: 127 Runtime: 1915",
        "Layer1: 100 Layer2: 135 Runtime: 3080",
        "Layer1: 100 Layer2: 153 Runtime: 3216"
      ]
    },
    {
      "timingResult": "Layer 1: 101 Completion time: 2650",
      "threadResults": [
        "Layer1: 101 Layer2: 109 Runtime: 2645",
        "Layer1: 101 Layer2: 129 Runtime: 1902",
        "Layer1: 101 Layer2: 134 Runtime: 1002",
        "Layer1: 101 Layer2: 136 Runtime: 1902"
      ]
    },
    {
      "timingResult": "Layer 1: 102 Completion time: 2914",
      "threadResults": [
        "Layer1: 102 Layer2: 106 Runtime: 1944",
        "Layer1: 102 Layer2: 131 Runtime: 2883",
        "Layer1: 102 Layer2: 154 Runtime: 2887",
        "Layer1: 102 Layer2: 158 Runtime: 2887"
      ]
    },
    {
      "timingResult": "Layer 1: 103 Completion time: 5219",
      "threadResults": [
        "Layer1: 103 Layer2: 107 Runtime: 1946",
        "Layer1: 103 Layer2: 128 Runtime: 981",
        "Layer1: 103 Layer2: 137 Runtime: 5207",
        "Layer1: 103 Layer2: 138 Runtime: 1938"
      ]
    },
    {
      "timingResult": "Layer 1: 104 Completion time: 1468",
      "threadResults": [
        "Layer1: 104 Layer2: 108 Runtime: 998",
        "Layer1: 104 Layer2: 130 Runtime: 997",
        "Layer1: 104 Layer2: 132 Runtime: 1446",
        "Layer1: 104 Layer2: 133 Runtime: 1461"
      ]
    },
    {
      "timingResult": "Layer 1: 105 Completion time: 2822",
      "threadResults": [
        "Layer1: 105 Layer2: 120 Runtime: 1930",
        "Layer1: 105 Layer2: 142 Runtime: 2145",
        "Layer1: 105 Layer2: 143 Runtime: 2800",
        "Layer1: 105 Layer2: 152 Runtime: 2798"
      ]
    },
    {
      "timingResult": "Layer 1: 155 Completion time: 3347",
      "threadResults": [
        "Layer1: 155 Layer2: 159 Runtime: 3216",
        "Layer1: 155 Layer2: 160 Runtime: 3215",
        "Layer1: 155 Layer2: 161 Runtime: 3272",
        "Layer1: 155 Layer2: 162 Runtime: 3346"
      ]
    },
    {
      "timingResult": "Layer 1: 164 Completion time: 3805",
      "threadResults": [
        "Layer1: 164 Layer2: 166 Runtime: 3342",
        "Layer1: 164 Layer2: 168 Runtime: 3547",
        "Layer1: 164 Layer2: 170 Runtime: 3666",
        "Layer1: 164 Layer2: 172 Runtime: 3803"
      ]
    },
    {
      "timingResult": "Layer 1: 165 Completion time: 3744",
      "threadResults": [
        "Layer1: 165 Layer2: 167 Runtime: 3347",
        "Layer1: 165 Layer2: 169 Runtime: 3667",
        "Layer1: 165 Layer2: 171 Runtime: 3667",
        "Layer1: 165 Layer2: 173 Runtime: 3742"
      ]
    },
    {
      "timingResult": "Layer 1: 174 Completion time: 4019",
      "threadResults": [
        "Layer1: 174 Layer2: 176 Runtime: 3802",
        "Layer1: 174 Layer2: 177 Runtime: 3802",
        "Layer1: 174 Layer2: 179 Runtime: 3802",
        "Layer1: 174 Layer2: 181 Runtime: 4018"
      ]
    },
    {
      "timingResult": "Layer 1: 175 Completion time: 4152",
      "threadResults": [
        "Layer1: 175 Layer2: 178 Runtime: 3802",
        "Layer1: 175 Layer2: 180 Runtime: 4118",
        "Layer1: 175 Layer2: 182 Runtime: 4118",
        "Layer1: 175 Layer2: 183 Runtime: 4151"
      ]
    },
    {
      "timingResult": "Layer 1: 184 Completion time: 4274",
      "threadResults": [
        "Layer1: 184 Layer2: 185 Runtime: 4207",
        "Layer1: 184 Layer2: 187 Runtime: 4263",
        "Layer1: 184 Layer2: 188 Runtime: 4263",
        "Layer1: 184 Layer2: 190 Runtime: 4273"
      ]
    },
    {
      "timingResult": "Layer 1: 186 Completion time: 5249",
      "threadResults": [
        "Layer1: 186 Layer2: 189 Runtime: 4250",
        "Layer1: 186 Layer2: 191 Runtime: 4516",
        "Layer1: 186 Layer2: 192 Runtime: 4575",
        "Layer1: 186 Layer2: 193 Runtime: 4646"
      ]
    },
    {
      "timingResult": "Layer 1: 194 Completion time: 4418",
      "threadResults": [
        "Layer1: 194 Layer2: 202 Runtime: 4264",
        "Layer1: 194 Layer2: 209 Runtime: 4264",
        "Layer1: 194 Layer2: 211 Runtime: 4101",
        "Layer1: 194 Layer2: 213 Runtime: 4035"
      ]
    },
    {
      "timingResult": "Layer 1: 195 Completion time: 4800",
      "threadResults": [
        "Layer1: 195 Layer2: 200 Runtime: 4643",
        "Layer1: 195 Layer2: 205 Runtime: 4328",
        "Layer1: 195 Layer2: 207 Runtime: 4274",
        "Layer1: 195 Layer2: 208 Runtime: 4166"
      ]
    },
    {
      "timingResult": "Layer 1: 196 Completion time: 4676",
      "threadResults": [
        "Layer1: 196 Layer2: 199 Runtime: 4520",
        "Layer1: 196 Layer2: 206 Runtime: 4100",
        "Layer1: 196 Layer2: 210 Runtime: 3829",
        "Layer1: 196 Layer2: 212 Runtime: 4101"
      ]
    },
    {
      "timingResult": "Layer 1: 197 Completion time: 4881",
      "threadResults": [
        "Layer1: 197 Layer2: 198 Runtime: 4595",
        "Layer1: 197 Layer2: 201 Runtime: 4707",
        "Layer1: 197 Layer2: 203 Runtime: 4514",
        "Layer1: 197 Layer2: 204 Runtime: 4328"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I make this service more performant?

Comment: Are you running this on a computer with 96 physical processor cores?  Did you already have 96 open and valid database connections ready to go? (if not Does your development database support concurrent connection opening at that level?) Does your development database have the capacity to parallelise I/O to that level?

Comment: Just brushed up on my threading knowledge; I only have 8 cores, or 16 threads. Thus yes, while my threads may be running in parallel they are sharing resources and slowing down the execution times. Removing my repository call got me my base execution time on my machine. I checked the development database aws (t2.micro) and it handles up to 66 connections. Logs do not show it only getting to 23 max. Mysql CPU max 9%, Memory 80% free.

Comment: I would suggest the first step is configuring the environment to have the maximum supported number of DB connections *already open* and available in a pool and see how that influences your results.  (and probably not bother attempt to parallelize beyond the maximum number of concurrent connections supported.)

Comment: And realize that if this is all a development system and the physical storage is a desktop grade spinning magnetic hard disk (or even a 'cheap' SSD really), trying to have 66 simultaneous reads isn't really going to speed up the overall operation.... ;)